# Exclude specific name in regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, python-2.7, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have multiple directories with names like `app1.6.11`, `app1.7.12`, `app1.8.34`, `test1`, `test2`.

I want to match regex for all the directories which start with `app` and to exclude `app1.8.34`.

I have tried:

```
^(app.+)[^(app1.8.34)]
```

Comment: Try [`^app(?!1.8.34).+`](https://regex101.com/r/nRinLq/2)

Comment: thanks @S.Jovan  It's working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match just the dot, you should escape it `\.` it or else it would match any character.

You could use a negative lookahead:

[`^app(?!1\.8\.34).+$`](https://regex101.com/r/BnN9HZ/1)

That would match

```
^          # The beginning of the string
app        # Match app
(?!        # Negative lookahead that asserts what follows is not
  1\.8\.34 # Match 1.8.34
)          # Close negative lookahead
.+         # Match any character one or more times
$          # End of the string
```